# How to customize/change 3xx status pages in Apache?

Tags: apache

How can I customize the 3xx status pages Apache? I am able to customize the 4xx and 5xx error pages using the `ErrorDocument` directive. I have tried the same for the 3xx status pages, but no good. I am unable to find any documentation about this from Apache. Please let me know if the 3xx status codes pages can be customized. And if so, let me know how to do it. Thanks in advance.

Why am I doing this?
I need to do this for testing purposes. This might just be of no good!

Comment: As far as I know 3xx status are for redirections so you don't have any error message to customize but a nice landing page for users redirected. But perhaps do you have a more concrete example?

Comment: Can you explain more about why your testing needs customized pages?   3xx statuses do come with a simple page with a link to the destination of the redirect.   However, modern browsers never show this page to users, they just change the URL.

Comment: @gael, just try PHP cURL for the redirect URL, and you will see the page. They do have a page. Read my next comment to know more.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, hey, I am trying to make Apache as customized a possible. And what I asked is not really needed I believe. But would be useful in some way. Yes, mordern browsers do not show the page. But cURL does. So, if someone uses cURL on my website, I thought why not just customize the page, and say like ***If you are seeing this page, your browser did not redirect to the destination page.***, which will not happen in most browsers, but just testing if it is possible.

Comment: Does anyone have a legitimate reason to use cURL in what you're planning to do? If not, wouldn't the message be more like this? "If you are seeing this page, you're a robot and you've been scraping my content. Please hold while we redirect you to CIA.gov." Anyway, if you do place a message there (that's displayed long enough to actually be seen by anyone) then you've also introduced another step in the redirection process. Even a slight delay will cause some people to leave, just like a slow loading website, and bots may assume the custom page is where your redirect ends.